# Android textureView stretched

Tags: android, android-camera2, stretched

`SurfaceTexture` preview is stretched! I'm developing a camera2 app. Every device is working bad. The preview for video and photo is stretched.

```
public class CamActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 1;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    Animation animFadeOut, textAnimFadeOut;
    ImageView viewFadeOut;
    TextView  textFadeOut, Lado;

    private TextureView textureView;
    private FloatingActionButton btnCapture;

    //Check state orientation of output image
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0,0);
    }

    private String cameraId;
    private CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    private CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSessions;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
    private Size imageDimension;
    private ImageReader imageReader;

    //Save to FILE
    private File file;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;
    private boolean mFlashSupported;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;

    CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraDevice = camera;
            createCameraPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            cameraDevice.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int i) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice=null;
        }
    };


    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cam);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);

        Lado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lado_armadilha);
        Lado.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("lado_armadilha"));

        viewFadeOut = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.viewFadeOut);
        animFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade);
        viewFadeOut.startAnimation(animFadeOut);

        textFadeOut =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textFadeOut);
        textAnimFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fade_text);
        textFadeOut.startAnimation(textAnimFadeOut);

        textureView = (TextureView)findViewById(R.id.textureView);
        //From Java 1.4 , you can use keyword 'assert' to check expression true or false
        assert textureView != null;
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        btnCapture = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
        btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                takePicture();
            }
        });
    }

    private void takePicture() {
        if(cameraDevice == null)
            return;
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
            Size[] jpegSizes = null;
            if(characteristics != null)
                jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)
                    .getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);

            Log.i("JPEG_SIZE", "" + jpegSizes[0].getWidth());
            Log.i("JPEG_SIZE", "" + jpegSizes[0].getHeight());

            //Capture image with custom size
            int width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
            int height =jpegSizes[0].getHeight();

            if(jpegSizes == null && jpegSizes.length < 0)
            {
                width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
                height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
            }
            final ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width,height,ImageFormat.JPEG,1);
            List<Surface> outputSurface = new ArrayList<>(2);
            outputSurface.add(reader.getSurface());
            outputSurface.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));

            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

            //Check orientation base on device
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION,ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));

            file = new File(getIntent().getStringExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT));

            ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
                    Image image = null;
                    try {
                        image = reader.acquireNextImage();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        save(bytes);
                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        Log.e("ioexception", e.getMessage());
                    }
                    finally {
                        if(image != null)
                            image.close();
                    }
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtra("Bitmap",file.getAbsolutePath());
                    setResult(1,intent);
                    finish();
                }
                private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                    OutputStream outputStream = null;
                    try {
                        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        outputStream.write(bytes);
                    } finally {
                        if(outputStream != null)
                            outputStream.close();
                    }
                }
            };

            reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener,mBackgroundHandler);
            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                    Toast.makeText(CamActivity.this, "Saved "+file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };

            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurface, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    try {
                        cameraCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(),captureListener,mBackgroundHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {

                }
            },mBackgroundHandler);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createCameraPreview() {

        try {
            SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture !=    null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(), imageDimension.getHeight());

            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    if (cameraDevice == null)
                        return;
                    cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                    updatePreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Toast.makeText(CamActivity.this, "Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void updatePreview() {
        if(cameraDevice == null)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE,CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        try {
            cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(),null,mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void openCamera() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            assert map != null;
            imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
            //Check realtime permission if run higher API 23
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                },REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                return;
            }
            manager.openCamera(cameraId,stateCallback,null);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {
            openCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION)
        {
            if(grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You can't use camera without permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startBackgroundThread();
        if(textureView.isAvailable())
            openCamera();
        else
            textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        stopBackgroundThread();
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread= null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Background");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please correct your post, its not understandable at all. What is the problem you are facing? Kindly take your time to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice? and this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please supply activity_cam.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TextureView will by default just stretch whatever images you give it into its view dimensions.  So if you give it a 1920x1080 buffer (16:9 aspect ratio) but its dimensions are 1600x1200 (4:3), you'll get a vertically squished image shown.

Take a look at the [AutoFitTextureView](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/AutoFitTextureView.java) in the Camera2Basic sample from Google.
It tries to ensure that its aspect ratio matches that of the camera, but it does require you to set its layout parameters correctly (and it has to be in a layout container that allows its children some flexibility in sizing).

Comment: Thaks Eddy Talvala. In order to solve this, I have to firstly identify the mobile device and then apply set the specific  dimension  for it.